# Получить значения из json php

Tags: php, json

Подскажите как получить значения _value 24,7 и file images/237.jpg

```
$string = '{ "46ffacdf-8009-4e7f-9076-1f7f59b152ee": { "variations": { "0": { "_value": { "value": "24,73" }, "_sku": { "value": "79" } } }, "selected": { }, "values": { "0": { } }, "default_variant": "0" }, "48a14646-9b57-44eb-98bc-9c34139bfcd6": { "0": { "file": "images\/237.jpg", "title": "", "link": "", "target": "0", "rel": "" } }, "fff28767-8e69-4c58-ac8b-9ce290c38548": { "0": { "value": "" } }, "8056b532-4837-4514-9d20-6399215a93d9": { "value": "1" } }';


$result_parse = json_decode($string, TRUE);
```

Comment: [Доступ к элементам массива](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing). Для того, чтобы понять структуру массива, можно его вывести в удобочитаемом виде: `var_dump()`, `var_export()` и `print_r()`

Comment: эти поля единственные во всем файле, или могут встречаться более чем 1 раз?

Comment: могут несколько раз

Comment: Deonis, доступ к элементам можно получить когда знаешь имя массива, а вот когда нет?

Answer (score 0):

Просто обращайтесь к JSON как к массиву:

```php
$string = '{ "46ffacdf-8009-4e7f-9076-1f7f59b152ee": { "variations": { "0": { "_value": { "value": "24,73" }, "_sku": { "value": "79" } } }, "selected": { }, "values": { "0": { } }, "default_variant": "0" }, "48a14646-9b57-44eb-98bc-9c34139bfcd6": { "0": { "file": "images\/237.jpg", "title": "", "link": "", "target": "0", "rel": "" } }, "fff28767-8e69-4c58-ac8b-9ce290c38548": { "0": { "value": "" } }, "8056b532-4837-4514-9d20-6399215a93d9": { "value": "1" } }';

$result_parse = json_decode($string, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

$value = $result_parse['46ffacdf-8009-4e7f-9076-1f7f59b152ee']['variations'][0]['_value']['value']; // 24,73
$filePath = $result_parse['48a14646-9b57-44eb-98bc-9c34139bfcd6'][0]['file']; // images/237.jpg

var_dump($value);
var_dump($filePath);
```

Comment: Да если  бы только не одно но массивы 46ffacdf-8009-4e7f-9076-1f7f59b152ee и 48a14646-9b57-44eb-98bc-9c34139bfcd6 постоянно меняются названия, и я уже голову сломал как добраться до значений

Comment: Я бы уже давно сам распарсил

Comment: Тогда Вы неправильно вопрос сформулировали

Comment: Возможно, простите

Comment: @ВячеславБелов значит циклом перебирай foreach()

Comment: Да если бы я знал) Не силён в этом)

Answer (score 0):

**В данном конкретном случае** можно просто пробежаться по массиву и взять значения из первого и второго элементов. Даже если они будут в 3 или 4 элементе массива код сработает.

```
$string = '{ "46ffacdf-8009-4e7f-9076-1f7f59b152ee": { "variations": { "0": { "_value": { "value": "24,73" }, "_sku": { "value": "79" } } }, "selected": { }, "values": { "0": { } }, "default_variant": "0" }, "48a14646-9b57-44eb-98bc-9c34139bfcd6": { "0": { "file": "images\/237.jpg", "title": "", "link": "", "target": "0", "rel": "" } }, "fff28767-8e69-4c58-ac8b-9ce290c38548": { "0": { "value": "" } }, "8056b532-4837-4514-9d20-6399215a93d9": { "value": "1" } }';

$string = json_decode($string, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);


foreach ($string as $item){
    
    if (isset($item['variations'][0]['_value']['value'])) $value = $item['variations'][0]['_value']['value'];
     if (isset($item[0]['file'])) $file = $item[0]['file'];
}

echo $value;
echo "\n";
echo $file;
//24,73
//images/237.jpg
```

https://3v4l.org/tbcaD#focus=7.4.16